# Check BadUSB or similar threats via software

Tags: windows, linux, software, usb-drive, badusb

I recently purchased a fake USB flash drive for its cool and beautiful case. I know that the seller modified the firmware so that it shows a different capacity to the operating system, but I am not sure if he modified the firmware to make it a BadUSB or injected any low-level malware into the flash drive's chip or other components. Is there any way to check (using software) without breaking the physical case?